# Simple way of finding the index of an item in a generic list

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I'm trying to get the next item in a list of strings (postal codes). Normally I'd just foreach till I find it and then get the next in the list but I'm trying to be a bit more intuitive and compact than that (more of an exercise than anything).

I can find it easily with a lambda:

```
List<string> postalCodes = new List<string> { "A1B", "A2B", "A3B" };
currentPostalCode = "A2B";
postalCodes.Find((s) => s == currentPostalCode);
```

Which is cool and all, and I properly get "A2B", but I'd prefer the index than the value.

Comment: postalCodes.IndexOf(currentPostalCode)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `IndexOf` method (this is a standard method of the generic `List<T>` class):

```
List<string> postalCodes = new List<string> { "A1B", "A2B", "A3B" }; 
currentPostalCode = "A2B"; 
int index = postalCodes.IndexOf(currentPostalCode);
```

For more information, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Just switch from Find(...) to FindIndex(...)

```
List<string> postalCodes = new List<string> { "A1B", "A2B", "A3B" }; 
currentPostalCode = "A2B"; 
postalCodes.FindIndex(s => s == currentPostalCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int indexofA2B = postalCodes.IndexOf("A2B");
```

Answer (score 0):

what about something like

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "A1B", "A2B", "A3B" };

names.Select((item, idx) => new {Item = item, Index = idx})
    .Where(t=>t.Index > names.IndexOf("A2B"))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```